# install natlink and dragonfly for python2.7 in windows10

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-dragonfly

I want to implement speech recognition in my windows10 using python2.7. Is it possible to install natlink for python2.7? Because i found that it is only available for python 2.5. If anybody knows how to get natlink and dragonfly for python 2.7 then please guide me. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, I'm doing it on Win7. I was able to successfully set it up multiple times, when following the following directions exactly:
http://qh.antenna.nl/unimacro/installation/installation.html

And that often included downloading and using the exactly supplied versions they zipped up for use. I don't know if it will work for Win10.

Also, if you can get it working with python 2.5, there's nothing stopping you from having multiple versions on your system.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Dragon Naturally Speaking 13 Premium + Natlink-4.1 ([from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/natlink/files/natlink/natlinktest4.1/)) + Dragonfly with python2.7 on my Windows 8 machine. I also had to install WxPython AFAIR. I had to do a few tests, but this combination works fine. I was able to run some basic tests.

Comment: Don't forget to mention pywin32.

Comment: Hey, this is old af but can you tell me how i get Dragonfly to work and where i have to specify grammars? I installed everything and Natlink shows up on dragon start, but now i dont know what to do